# Show that Turing-decidable languages are closed under set difference

Tags: computer-science

Can we use the proof of turing-decidable languages being closed under complement to show that turing-decidable languages are closed under set difference?

Comment: Provided you also know that turing-recognizable languages are closed under intersection. See i.e. http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2006-07/F/2001/handouts/lect18.pdf

Comment: would it be the same proof as complement? if M is a tm that decides L, run M on w, reject if M accepts and accept if M rejects?